# Cant access .Net Core app via Docker on Windows (localhost)

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a docker file and exposed the port. I also setup my program.cs to read those URLs + ports yet I can't access it.

From what I can see in the docker console is that my app is running. I just cant reach it.

I have tried localhost:5024 and 172.17.0.2:5024 but it just doesn't hit it.

[image]

Here is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5024

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY Api/*.csproj ./Api/

RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY Api/. ./Api/
COPY Api.Core/. ./Api.Core/

WORKDIR /app/Api
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/Api/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

This is my program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:5024");
            });
```

And I run these commands to get it running

```
docker build -f Api/Dockerfile -t quiplogs_api .
docker run -d -p 5024:80 --name app quiplogs_api
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### short Answer

change your `docker run` command to the below:

`docker run -d -p 5024:5024 --name app quiplogs_api`

Access the api using localhost:5024/api....
or
change UseUrls to use port 80
and everything stays the same

#### Long Answer

In the world of docker, there are two networks.

First is inside the docker world, where all the containers are running.
The second is the host machine.
When you are writing a docker app you have to be very careful about which network you are in.

-p is not for the ports it is the publish option.

with this switch, you establish a link between the host network and the docker network.
Your command is saying publish this container's host port 5024 and map it to the docker network port 80.
But UseUrls is actually configuring it to run on port 5024 within docker. A slight semantic discrepancy. The new command fixes that. Or you could change UseUrls to use port 80.